# UPDATE statement in SQLite with nested FROM and JOIN

Tags: sql, postgresql, sqlite

I currently have an SQL statment:

```
UPDATE table_1 SET
  property_1=b.value_1,
  property_2=b.value_2,
  property_3=b.value_3
FROM (
  SELECT a.property_4, a.property_5, b.value_2, b.value_3
  FROM (
    SELECT id1 AS property_4, MAX(id2) AS property_5
    FROM table_2
    WHERE
      id1 IN (...) AND
      id2 NOT IN (...)
    ) a
    JOIN table_3 b ON
      a.property_5 = b.id
) a
WHERE
table_1.id = a.property_4
```

which works fine on our production postgresql db, however the syntax for UPDATE is different in SQLite (what we use in test) and I am finding my self quite stuck as to how to convert it. The error I receive is `Error: syntax error near FROM`. If anyone is a SQLite whiz I would greatly appreciate some guidance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since SQLite doesn't support UPDATE with JOIN/FROM clause. You can use `CTE` & `SubQuery` to do it alternatively:

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT a.property_4, b.value_1, b.value_2, b.value_3
    FROM (
    SELECT id1 AS property_4, MAX(id2) AS property_5
    FROM table_2
    WHERE
      id1 IN (...) AND
      id2 NOT IN (...)
    ) a 
    JOIN table_3 b ON
    a.property_5 = b.id    
)

UPDATE table_1 SET
  property_1=(select value_1 from cte where cte.property_4 = id)
  property_2=(select value_2 from cte where cte.property_4 = id)
  property_3=(select value_3 from cte where cte.property_4 = id)
WHERE
id IN (select property_4 from cte)
```

Comment: This worked perfectly! Thanks so much! It should be noted that since we use `CTE` we don't specify b.value_1, b.value_2, b.value_3, we just use value_1, value_2, value_3.